# Creating dynamic fields in Powermail 2.x

Tags: typo3, typoscript, extbase

[image]I have a doubt with powermail 2.x extension .

My actual requirement is , I have a form (custom extension) through which I can search some places using zip code. So once user submits the value (eg zip code) , the webiste will be redirected to page where I list all available places under that zip code as link. When a user clicks on that link , Website will be redirected to another page where I hvae configured powermail 2.x extension . What I want to implement is , based on link clicked (I will be passing `place_id` through the link and each place have some membership types).I want to show a set of membership types in radio buttons(Fetched from another table using the arguments from url). and this items should be there in preview and mail as well.

The same thing we can implement using $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXTCONF']['powermail']['PM_FieldHook'] in powermail 1.6 ?

How we can implement the same in powermail 2.x??

Any help would be appropriated ?

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Finally I have managed to fix it by myself.

All you have to do is,

Add a new check box field in the powermial form , In the extended tab , you can assign a typoscript variable something like lib.products .

```
lib.products = CONTENT
lib.products {
table = pages
select {
  pidInList = xxx
}
renderObj = COA
renderObj {
  10 = COA
  10 {
    10 = TEXT
    10.dataWrap = {field:title}[\n]
  }
}
}
```

Above code will generate dynamic radio buttons in the frontend.Again if you wish to like create custom field type in powermail field.

```
tx_powermail.flexForm.type.addFieldOptions.new = Name of the field
tx_powermail.flexForm.type.addFieldOptions.new.dataType = 1 (If it is an array)
```

After that add the below typoscript code

```
plugin.tx_powermail.view {
 partialRootPath >
 partialRootPaths {
    10 = EXT:powermail/Resources/Private/Partials/
    20 = EXT:extension/Resources/Private/Partials/
   }
 }
```

and create a template file`EXT:extension/Resources/Private/Partials/New.html`.In that file , you can include field(checkboxes radio buttons or selectboxes).

After that

```
$signalSlotDispatcher = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\SignalSlot\Dispatcher');
$signalSlotDispatcher->connect(
  'In2code\Powermail\Controller\FormController',
  'formActionBeforeRenderView',
  'HEV\Extension\Controller\FormController',
  'customfucntion',
   FALSE
);
```

we have to implement the signal slot available in powermail 2.X

and in the the

```
/**
 * @param \In2code\Powermail\Domain\Model\Form $form
 * @param \In2code\Powermail\Controller\FormController $pObj
 */
public function manipulateMailObjectOnCreate($form, $pObj) {
    $sectionNr      = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::_GP("SID");
    if ( !isset( $sectionNr ))
    return ;
    foreach ( $form as $forms ){
        foreach( $forms->getPages() as $key => $pages){
            foreach ( $pages->getFields() as $fields ){
                switch ( $fields->getType() ){
                    case "new":
                        $fields->setMandatory(TRUE);
                        $fields->setCreateFromTyposcript('lib.products');
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```